# Build dynamic SQL query to sort records with limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Please consider the below scenario to understand my requirement.

I have list of the product types

```
Webinar, Summit, Intent
```

Story: There is an user(account) can have subscribed to any `(Webinar, Intent, Summit)` product types. If user subscribed to all above product_type then in response all product_type should be displayed by below given order 
**but the condition is we have show to only 6 records**.

I have a table called **test**

```
Table: test
+-----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id  | product_type |  status   | account_id | event_id |
+-----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|   1 | Summit       | Active    |          1 |      123 |
|   2 | Intent       | Pending   |          1 |      456 |
|   3 | Intent       | Completed |          1 |      789 |
|   4 | Webinar      | Completed |          1 |      321 |
|   5 | Summit       | Inactive  |          1 |      465 |
|   6 | Summit       | Completed |          1 |      126 |
|   7 | Intent       | Inactive  |          1 |      965 |
|   8 | Webinar      | Completed |          1 |      325 |
|   9 | Summit       | Pending   |          1 |      145 |
|  10 | Intent       | Pending   |          1 |      568 |
+-----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Column `product_type` can have different values like

```
"Webinar", "Intent", "Summit"
```

Column `status` can have different values like

```
"Pending", "Inactive", "Active", "Completed"
```

I want to sort records based on `status` column first then `product_type` column.

here is the sorting order:

```
status sorting order: Pending, Inactive, Active, Completed

product_type sorting order: Webinar, Summit, Intent 

//If any product_type with status Pending it should sort first then Inactive so on.

//If 2 different product_type like Intent and Summit having the same status then query should be sort by product_type
```

Please considering below scenario. Suppose an account have subscribed to total 30 product_type like

```
Total 10 Webinar: 5 pending and 5 Completed
Total 12 Summit: 6 Inactive and 6 Completed
Total 8 Intent: 4 Active and 4 Completed
```

As I already mentioned query must return only 6 records. If we consider above sorting order then query should product below result.

```
4 pending Webinar
1 Inactive Summit
1 Active Intent
```

Scenario: 1

`Suppose in request I get account_id = 1 and productTypes = "Webinar, Intent, Summit"`

According to `test` table account_id = 1 subscribed to all `(Webinar, Intent, Summit)` product_type so in response we have to show all product_type associated to an account with given sorting order (status first then product_type).
so query should return below output.

```
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id | product_type |  status   | account_id | event_id |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|  9 | Summit       | Pending   |          1 |      145 |
|  2 | Intent       | Pending   |          1 |      456 |
| 10 | Intent       | Pending   |          1 |      568 |
|  5 | Summit       | Inactive  |          1 |      465 |
|  7 | Intent       | Inactive  |          1 |      965 |
|  4 | Webinar      | Completed |          1 |      321 |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Scenario: 2
`Suppose in request I get account_id = 1 and productTypes = "Webinar, Intent"`

By the way account_id = 1 subscribed to all `(Webinar, Intent, Summit)` product_type but in request we are getting only 
productTypes = `Webinar, Intent` so query should sort by (status first then product_type) for `Webinar, Intent`

Expected output is.

```
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| id | product_type |  status   | account_id | event_id |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
|  2 | Intent       | Pending   |          1 |      456 |
| 10 | Intent       | Pending   |          1 |      568 |
|  7 | Intent       | Inactive  |          1 |      965 |
|  4 | Webinar      | Completed |          1 |      321 |
|  8 | Webinar      | Completed |          1 |      325 |
|  3 | Intent       | Completed |          1 |      789 |
+----+--------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Here is my sample Query,

Here I am considering in request I will get `account_id = 1` and productTypes = `Webinar, Intent, Summit`

So desire output will be Scenario: 1

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    test
WHERE
    account_id = 1 AND
    product_type IN ('Webinar' , 'Summit', 'Intent')
    //product_type is coming in request so I will update dynamically
    AND status IN ('Pending' , 'Inactive', 'Active', 'Completed')
ORDER BY 
    FIELD(status,
        'Pending',
        'Inactive',
        'Active',
        'Completed') , 
    FIELD(product_type,
        'Webinar',
        'Summit',
        'Intent') 
        limit 6;// as we have to show only 6 records
```

I am considering I can not achieve expected ouput with single query, Can someone help me to fix this query.
Thank you.

Comment: In scenario 1 why does it not return 5 pending webinars and 1 inactive summit?

Comment: @Nick Please consider  account = 1associated to Webinar, Summit and Intent productType, if an account associated to all product type we have to show each productType in response.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't scenario 1, it was the un-numbered scenario before that

Comment: Your query gives exactly the results you want https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4GuKpWgC3w63peZC3HPC3/0 what is the problem?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you want to vary the number of of product types in the query based on the number of distinct product types the account has? or do you want to provide the product types (in which case you should build the query in your front end)

Comment: @Nick, Please add 6 more  `Webinar` with status `Pending` for an `account = 1` so you will get only `6 Webinar Pending` in result. but query should return `4 Pending Webinar` then `1 Pending Summit` and at last `1 Pending Intent`. Please test you will get different result.

Comment: @Nizamuddin that's not how it works. You're supposed to create an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you are having. As your question currently stands, there is no problem to be solved. Feel free to edit my demo yourself to demonstrate your issue, and then [edit] the question to explain what is going wrong in that demo.

Comment: @Nick Now please check `https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4GuKpWgC3w63peZC3HPC3/1` , I am getting only 6 `Pending Webinar` product type even though `account = 1` associated to all product types

Comment: @Nizamuddin you need to click the `Update` link at the top of the page

Comment: @Nick I am sorry I wasn't know that, I did.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4GuKpWgC3w63peZC3HPC3/1

Comment: @Nick I believe you got my problem

Comment: Most likely you have to fetch product types in separate queries and the do logic in code.

Comment: So what is your *desired* result for that scenario? Based on the sort order you have described in the question, the query returns the expected result.

Comment: @ex4 I was thinking same but I don't want to hit DB multiple times as It reduce the application performance

Comment: @Nick Sorting logic works fine but Query fetching entire records which is not expected. I want to fetch only 6 records. as `account = 1` subscribed to all product types then why I am not getting all product_type with `4 Pending Webinar`, `1 Pending Summit` and at last `1 Pending Intent`.

Comment: If you did that kind of logic in SQL it would probably be so complicated that running that query once would be slower than running 3 or 5 simple queries.

Comment: So you want to fetch *at least one* record of each product type in the query, even if the sort order would mean that you would get 6 of one product and none of the others?

Comment: @Nick Yes, Query should fetch at least one record of each product type.

Comment: @Nick This is quite complex scenario.. Can please tell me how can I achieve desire output.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: MYSQL version = 5.6.44-log

Comment: @Nizamuddin it is a complex problem in MySQL prior to 8. Here's something that might help you on the road: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4GuKpWgC3w63peZC3HPC3/2

Comment: @Nick, Thank for your effort I wil run your and let you know the result by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to guarantee at least one record per `product_type`.  You can do that using `row_number()` and then adding the rest of your filter conditions:

```
order by (row_number() over (partition by product_type
                             order by field(status, 'Pending', 'Inactive', 'Active', 'Completed'), id
                            ) = 1) desc,  -- first row first for each product_type

         field(status, 'Pending', 'Inactive', 'Active', 'Completed'),
         field(product_type, 'Webinar', 'Summit', 'Intent') 
limit 6;
```

Comment: It's MySQL 5.6 so no `row_number()`

Comment: @Nick, I have updated `2 Pending Intent` status with `Completed` now in result not getting `Intent` product_type.. Please have a look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4GuKpWgC3w63peZC3HPC3/4

Comment: Today is my last day to deliver the task, I am using my query which I had mentioned in description and will use `Java 8` to do some filtration.

Comment: @Nizamuddin as Gordon has shown in his answer, you will need a solution based around row numbers to make this work. Unfortunately row numbers are tricky in MySQL versions before 8. I would suggest googling MySQL 5.7 emulate row number and then trying to make a query based on that.

Comment: @Nizamuddin It might be easiest to do this filtering in Java.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I am good in java rather than SQL, Thanks for help.